# Check if all values were successfully read from std::istream

Tags: c++, iostream

Let's say I have a file that has

```
100 text
```

If I try reading 2 numbers using ifstream, it would fail because `text` is not a number. Using fscanf I'll know it failed by checking its return code:

```
if (2 != fscanf(f, "%d %d", &a, &b))
    printf("failed");
```

But when using iostream instead of stdio, how do I know it failed?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Its actually as (if not more) simple:

```
ifstream ifs(filename);
int a, b;
if (!(ifs >> a >> b))
   cerr << "failed";
```

Get used to that format, by the way. as it comes in *very* handy (even more-so for continuing *positive* progression through loops).

Comment: -1 because: 1. I don't like if conditions with side-effects. 2. This breaks the "principle of least astonishment" - one does not know what to expect from the value of the `(ifs >> a >> b)` expression.

Answer (score 6):

If one' using GCC with `-std=c++11` or `-std=c++14` she may encounter:

```
error: cannot convert ‘std::istream {aka std::basic_istream<char>}’ to ‘bool’
```

**Why?**
The C++11 standard made `bool` operator call explicit ([ref](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool)). Thus it's necessary to use:

```
std::ifstream ifs(filename);
int a, b;
if (!std::static_cast<bool>(ifs >> a >> b))
  cerr << "failed";
```

Personally I prefer below use of `fail` function:

```
std::ifstream ifs(filename);
int a, b;
ifs >> a >> b
if (ifs.fail())
  cerr << "failed";
```

Comment: On failure, shouldn't you do something like `throw std::system_error(errno, std::generic_category());` ? Anyway, +1.